# remapping Caps Lock to Ctrl key in tmux

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I'm using tmux 2.0 on CentOS 6.7(without X).
How can I use `Caps Lock` instead of `Ctrl` in tmux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do it at the tmux layer. The tmux man page `man tmux`
has a section titled `KEY BINDINGS` which lists the special keys that can be
mapped within tmux. Caps lock is not one of them:

> In addition, the following special key names are accepted: Up, Down, Left,
>   Right, BSpace, BTab, DC (Delete), End, Enter, Escape, F1 to F12, Home, IC
>   (Insert), NPage/PageDown/PgDn, PPage/PageUp/PgUp, Space, and Tab.

Fortunately, you should be able to do it easily at the CentOS layer.

There are a few ways of doing it, I prefer the following:

`setxkbmap -layout us -option ctrl:nocaps`

`xmodmap -e 'clear Lock'`

`xmodmap -e 'keycode 0x7e = Control_R'`

`xmodmap -e 'add Control = Control_R'`

Which you can put into your `.bashrc` file, or wherever commands are run on startup of your system.

There may also be a way to change the keyboard layout in a configuration program within CentOS. I'm not very familiar with it, but Caps Lock to Control is a pretty common request and you should be able to find it if you search for doing it in CentOS, Linux, or anything other than tmux.